# How to run a multi-processing pool using gtts in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, gtts

I'm trying to do bulk text to audio conversion without using cloud services like AWS polly.

*gtts* gives good quality text to speech but requires an internet connection to get results. Running *tts* for individual strings using this code for example is very slow.

`post_id` and `summary` are 2 columns of a dataframe that have ids and summaries of news articles respectively. I'm running in Visual Studio Code in a Python file on Windows 10.

```
from gtts import gTTS

for row_id, row_summary in zip(df.post_id, df.summary):
        tts = gTTS(row_summary, lang='en', tld='ca')
        tts.save('.\summary_audio\gtts_summary_'+str(row_id)+'.mp3')
```

This works but takes half an hour for 100 summaries, which is slow.

I've tried using pooling like so:

```
from gtts import gTTS
from multiprocessing import Pool, get_context

def generate_audio(row_id, row_summary):
         tts = gTTS(row_summary, lang='en', tld='ca')
         file_name = '.\summary_audio\gtts_summary_'+str(row_id)+'.mp3'
         tts.save(file_name)
         return None

pool_input = list(zip(df.post_id, df.summary))
with get_context("spawn").Pool() as p:
         p.starmap(generate_audio, pool_input)
```

But I end up getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path, 
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 265, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projects\NLP_Cron\cron_audio.py", line 100, in <module>
    [os.remove(f) for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(".mp3")]
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projects\NLP_Cron\cron_audio.py", line 100, in <listcomp>
    [os.remove(f) for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(".mp3")]
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'gtts_summary_4a063dea-9469-4633-87bc-b4a2f2e3f1ba.mp3'
```

Does this mean it won't run in a pool unless the developer of the *gtts* library enables it? Or am I simply doing something wrong here?

Edit: Also before doing this, I'm creating a folder called *summary_audio* to save the files to if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because i realize I was running the pool process inside a function. The pool statement has to run in the main section. Only then it works as intended. Here is a full example.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, get_context
import pandas as pd
from gtts import gTTS

df_col1 = [1,3,4,5,6,7]
df_col2 = ["Hi", "Bye", "Why?", "Cry", "Die", "Pie", "Shy"]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(df_col1, df_col2), columns = ['post_id', 'summary'])

def generate_audio(row_id, row_summary):
         tts = gTTS(row_summary, lang='en', tld='ca')
         file_name = '.\summary_audio\gtts_summary_'+str(row_id)+'.mp3'
         return tts.save(file_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool_input = list(zip(df.post_id, df.summary))
    with Pool(3) as p:
         p.starmap(generate_audio, pool_input)
    p.join()
```

Also it wont make sense to use gtts with pooling in the first place because you will get rate limited.